# entire function in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

$$
y = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll}
\dfrac{\cos z}{z^2-\left( \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)^2}, & z \ne \pm \dfrac{\pi}{2}\\
-\dfrac{1}{\pi}, & z = \pm \dfrac{\pi}{2}\\
\end{array} \right.
$$

$$
\dfrac{\cos z}{\left(z-\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)\left(z+\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)}=\dfrac{\dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}}{\left(z-\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)\left(z+\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)}=\ldots
$$

I need to prove that this is the entire function. I tried to write series representation, but I couldn't obtain as $\frac{\pi}2$.

Firstly, I need to obtain series representation and then I should show that it converges to $-\frac{1}{\pi}$ at $z=\frac{\pi}2$ , it should be analytic in all complex plane for be entire function.

How can I obtain that series?

Comment: You can take the limit along the real axis using L'Hospital's rule. If you show the function is bounded on some neighborhood of $\pi/2$, the Riemann removable singularity theorem implies that the limit in the complex plane exists as well.

Comment: The numerator vanishes at $\pm\pi/2$, so the overall function has no poles. Use a partial fraction decomposition to split up the denominator and then expand them into geometric series.

Comment: But I should show by seri representation

Comment: @1214: You mean **series**...

Comment: sorry,of course series